# Scala: How is Barrier Synchronization implemented?

Tags: scala, concurrency, semaphore

anyone has any idea how is `Barrier Synchronization` implemented internally in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala)? I am guessing it is using `Semaphores`, but I am wondering how exactly it works, does anyone know?

I guess one naive way to think of this might be to create an array of Semaphores one for each process. Any better / more efficient implementations?

Comment: When referring to general terms in computer science, it is usually helpful to put in a link to a wikipedia or some other authority describing the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sorry for this guys, I have found it after all. here it is in case anyone is interested.

```
class Barrier(n:Int){
  assert(n>1);
  private var waiting = 0; // number of processes currently waiting
  private val waitSem = new Semaphore; waitSem.down
  private val mutex = new Semaphore;

  def sync = {
    mutex.down;
    if(waiting==n-1){ waitSem.up; }
    else{ 
      waiting+=1; mutex.up; waitSem.down; 
      // Wait until woken
      waiting-=1; 
      if(waiting==0) mutex.up; else waitSem.up;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use either `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` or `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`.

Comment: Why do you prefer those to the above implementation?

Comment: @devilwontcry For three reasons: 1) They are standard interfaces, so people may know what they do beforehand, instead of having to find out; 2) They are well documented; 3) They are well tested, and quite likely to be bug-free. Your implementation, for instance, does not synchronize anywhere, resulting in a possible race condition while accessing `waiting`. The way it is written, it is possible for `waiting` to never reach `n+1` as well as never returning to `0`. Look up CyclicBarrier's source code for a comparison.

Comment: No no no! My implementation is correct 100%. That's why the `mutex` is there. It ensures that waiting is changed atomically.

Comment: @devilwontcry This is not a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` either, so I have to guess what `up` and `down` mean -- see #1 above. :-) Anyway, I see now that `waiting+=1` is protected by the mutex. However, `waiting-=1` is not. And that is _not_ a thread-safe operation.

Comment: Yes it is not, it is in Scala. And `waiting -= 1` is also protected from `waitSem`. The process waits for `waitSem.down` then does `waiting -= 1` inside it, so this is guarded as well.

Comment: @devilwontcry Mmmmm, I see. Ok, it seems to work indeed. But I trust Java implementation's better.

Comment: Oh yeah me too! No questions asked, I just have to do this in Scala for practice! :( Need to learn this language! pfff